# NumPy Indexing - all pairwise elements of lists of indices

Tags: python, numpy

When using slicing in NumPy, you get all pair-wise elements, e.g.:

```
>> im = np.arange(1,37).reshape((6, 6))
>> im[1:6:2,1:6:2]
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
       [20, 22, 34],
       [32, 34, 36]])
```

However when using lists/tuples of indices this behavior does not seem to be followed:

```
>> im[(1,3,5),(1,3,5)]
array([ 8, 22, 36])

>> im[[1,3,5],[1,3,5]]
array([ 8, 22, 36])
```

It is instead gets just the diagonal (in this case). This is problematic if you cannot specify indices as slices, for example `(1,3,4)` and `(1,3,6)`. For those two tuples I would expect to get all elements at `(1,1) (1,3) (1,6) (3,1) ...`

All the workarounds I can think of involve fleshing out every pair of elements which is incredibly expensive when trying to extract large numbers of elements from massive images. In MATLAB, `im([1,3,5],[1,3,5])` does what I would want. I know there are many tricks in NumPy's indexing and I am probably just missing some subtleties.

As a conclusion, example workarounds:

```
im[np.meshgrid([1,3,5], [1,3,5], indexing='ij')]
im[zip(*itertools.product([1,3,5], [1,3,5]))].reshape((3,3))
```

Comment: You are right, I originally have `order='F'` in the reshape command producing the transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`numpy.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
>>> im[np.ix_((1,3,5),(1,3,5))]
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
   [20, 22, 24],
   [32, 34, 36]])
```

Or you can directly do this:

```
>>> ix = np.array([1, 3, 5])
>>> iy = np.array([1, 3, 5])
>>> im[ix[:, np.newaxis], iy[np.newaxis, :]]
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
       [20, 22, 24],
       [32, 34, 36]])
```

Comment: Ah, so if the indices are column or row vectors this works. That looks to be the most promising.

Comment: Tested this out using your second example and it works great. I used the second one because the indices were already column vectors, so it looked like `im[ix,iy.T]`. That is quite clean and likely very efficient!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
i1 = [1,3,5]
i2 = [1,3,5]
print im[i1][:,i2].ravel()
```

Note a temporary array is created on first indexing. If your array is very big, it might be undesirable.

Comment: That does work (if you remove the `ravel`). However, the temporary created there may be larger than the temporary created with `meshgrid` (if less than half of the columns are taken). But it is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by other people is correct. Just to explain why this is happening.

From documentation of [Indexing on numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) -

> When indexing like - `x[obj]` - Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or **a tuple with at least one sequence object** or ndarray (of data type integer or bool).

Your case falls into the second , and hence `im[(1,3,5),(1,3,5)]` triggers Advanced indexing. And later on in the [documentation of *Advanced indexing*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) , it is explained -

> Advanced indexes always are [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting) and iterated as one:
>
> ```
> result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
>                        ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]
> ```
>
> Note that the result shape is identical to the (broadcast) indexing array shapes ind_1, ..., ind_N.

That it `result[i_1]` would be - `x[ind_1[i_1],ind_2[i_1],...ind_N[i_1]]`

The documentation suggest to use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) to achieve behavior similar to basic slicing -

> To achieve a behaviour similar to the basic slicing above, broadcasting can be used. The function [ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) can help with this broadcasting. This is best understood with an example.